# Change animation based on mouse screen position in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am developing an Isometric 2D game in Unity, using C# scripts. The character will be able to run in 8 different orientations.

I am trying to trigger a running animation depending on the mouse position. 
My script is working fine but I don't think is the best way to face this problem.

First of all, I have an enum with the possible orientations:

```
public enum Orientations {N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW,NONE}
```

I wrote a method that returns an Orientations value based in a movement. This is because I want to trigger an animation based on the movement, so the Character will always be looking at the direction of the movement:

```
public static Orientations GetOrientation(Vector2 movement)
    {
        if (movement.x == 0 && movement.y == 1)
        {
            return Orientations.N;
        }
        else if (movement.x == 1 && movement.y == 0)
        {
            return Orientations.E;
        }
        else if (movement.x == 0 && movement.y == -1)
        {
            return Orientations.S;
        }
        else if (movement.x == -1 && movement.y == 0)
        {
            return Orientations.W;
        }
        else if (movement.x == -1 && movement.y == 1)
        {
            return Orientations.NW;
        }
        else if (movement.x == 1 && movement.y == 1)
        {
            return Orientations.NE;
        }
        else if (movement.x == -1 && movement.y == -1)
        {
            return Orientations.SW;
        }
        else if (movement.x == 1 && movement.y == -1)
        {
            return Orientations.SE;
        }
        return Orientations.NONE;
    }
```

Next, I get the mouse angle between the character and the screen.

```
public static float GetMousePosition(Transform transform)
    {
        float cameraDistance = Camera.main.transform.position.y - transform.position.y;
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, cameraDistance));
        float angleRadius = Mathf.Atan2(mousePosition.y - transform.position.y, mousePosition.x - transform.position.x);
        float angle = (180 / Mathf.PI) * angleRadius;
        angle = (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
        return angle;
    }
```

Then, I transform the angle in a Vector2, so I am able to switch between triggering animations by the character movement and mouse position:

```
public static Vector2 AngleToVectorDirection(Transform transform)
    {
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(0,0);
        float angle = GetMousePosition(transform);

        if(angle >= 67.5 && angle < 112.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(0,1);
        }
        else if (angle >= 112.5 && angle < 157.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(-1,1);
        }
        else if (angle >= 157.5 && angle < 202.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
        }
        else if (angle >= 202.5 && angle < 247.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(-1, -1);
        }
        else if (angle >= 247.5 && angle < 292.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(0, -1);
        }
        else if (angle >= 292.5 && angle < 337.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(1, -1);
        }
        else if (angle >= 337.5 || angle < 22.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(1, 0);
        }
        else if (angle >= 22.5 && angle < 67.5)
        {
            direction = new Vector2(1, 1);
        }
        return direction;
    }
```

To finish, I return the Orientation as I mentioned:

```
public static Orientations GetOrientationByMovement(Transform transform, Vector2 movement)
    {
        Vector2 orientation;

        if (!Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            orientation = movement;
        }

        else
        {
            orientation = AngleToVectorDirection(transform);
        }
        return GetOrientation(orientation);
    }
```

This Orientation is received by an AnimationController script that triggers the animation.

I can not simply rotate the character, or flip sprite, or something like that because it is animation based.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing the work twice. So in an optimisation point of view that not ideal but in a design point of view that can be good to separate the works. The question is where does the movement parameter come from in the GetOrientationByMovement method? can you use instead the orientation enum? if yes then that simplifies your code greatly!
You end up with :

```
public static Orientations AngleToVectorDirection(Transform transform)
    {
        float angle = GetMousePosition(transform);

        if(angle >= 67.5 && angle < 112.5)
        {
            return Orientations.N;
        }
        else if (angle >= 112.5 && angle < 157.5)
        {
            return Orientations.NW;
        }
        else if (angle >= 157.5 && angle < 202.5)
        {
            return Orientations.W;
        }
        else if (angle >= 202.5 && angle < 247.5)
        {
            return Orientations.SW;
        }
        else if (angle >= 247.5 && angle < 292.5)
        {
            return Orientations.S;
        }
        else if (angle >= 292.5 && angle < 337.5)
        {
            return Orientations.SE;
        }
        else if (angle >= 337.5 || angle < 22.5)
        {
            return Orientations.E;
        }
        else if (angle >= 22.5 && angle < 67.5)
        {
            return Orientations.NE;
        }
    }
```

Also try to keep consistency in your code. if you use return value in the if statement do that for both function, in you use it outside do it everywhere. 
Note that in your implementation of the AngleToVectorDirection you don't need to create a new vector in the beginning since you cover all the angle that can be.

Comment: The parameter "movement" of GetOrientationByMovement comes directly from the CharacterController RawAxis, so I don't understand how can I use the Orientatios enum instead. 
Thanks for the answer, I defined the AngleToVectorDirection method that way because of I wanted to use the same method GetOrientation for both, but it's true that it will be process the same logic twice.

Comment: My concerne is the frequency this methods are used. I think you are better off using 2 methods to convert 2 type of data into what you want than using one that goes into the other. The code written is the same but the execution is twice as fast.
Also what will you do with the enum because there is quite some chance that you will have a switch to convert this enum into action no? why not keeping the vector then? (readability is a good answer, depending on the performance required ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

With the just released unity's 3.8f1 patch, I've found in them demo project a way to trigger animations in a really simple way.

I am just using the code you can find in the official site: 
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/18/isometric-2d-environments-with-tilemap/?_ga=2.120446600.1010886114.1552829987-288556513.1552829987

They use a IsometricCharacterRenderer script where use Animator.Play() passing as parameter a value of a string[], based on the player movement.

```
public static readonly string[] staticDirections = { "Static N", "Static NW", "Static W", "Static SW", "Static S", "Static SE", "Static E", "Static NE" };
public static readonly string[] runDirections = { "Run N", "Run NW", "Run W", "Run SW", "Run S", "Run SE", "Run E", "Run NE" };

public void SetDirection(Vector2 direction)
    {

        //use the Run states by default
        string[] directionArray = null;

        //measure the magnitude of the input.
        if (direction.magnitude < .01f)
        {
            //if we are basically standing still, we'll use the Static states
            //we won't be able to calculate a direction if the user isn't pressing one, anyway!
            directionArray = staticDirections;
        }
        else
        {
            //we can calculate which direction we are going in
            //use DirectionToIndex to get the index of the slice from the direction vector
            //save the answer to lastDirection
            directionArray = runDirections;
            lastDirection = DirectionToIndex(direction, 8);
        }

        //tell the animator to play the requested state
        animator.Play(directionArray[lastDirection]);
    }
```

And to get the direction index, they convert the movement in an angle, just how I did, but in a smart way.

```
public static int DirectionToIndex(Vector2 dir, int sliceCount)
    {
        //get the normalized direction
        Vector2 normDir = dir.normalized;
        //calculate how many degrees one slice is
        float step = 360f / sliceCount;
        //calculate how many degress half a slice is.
        //we need this to offset the pie, so that the North (UP) slice is aligned in the center
        float halfstep = step / 2;
        //get the angle from -180 to 180 of the direction vector relative to the Up vector.
        //this will return the angle between dir and North.
        float angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.up, normDir);
        //add the halfslice offset
        angle += halfstep;
        //if angle is negative, then let's make it positive by adding 360 to wrap it around.
        if (angle < 0)
        {
            angle += 360;
        }
        //calculate the amount of steps required to reach this angle
        float stepCount = angle / step;
        //round it, and we have the answer!
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(stepCount);
    }
```